# App crash on android version below 6 but work on above android 6 or 7 showing error android.view.InflateException:

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is the error message i am getting when my application is trying to install in android version 6 or 5. But no issue is coming in above version 6.Please give me some suggestions.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

this is my drawer.xml code.Why this is crashing in android Lollipop and 
Marshmallow.
I think error in this file So please comment.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/textcolor"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`

This is my gradle file :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

 dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
 }
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

  repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      }


   android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.yogwallpaper"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
 }

   dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
   core:3.0.1'
    }
```

Comment: share your gradle file.

Comment: please check gradle file

Comment: where you upload gradle file ?

Comment: ** I did Please Check Again**

Comment: I suspect, you have used `app:itemTextColor="@drawable/textcolor"`. The value should be a color or `ColorStateList`. You pointed it to `drawable`

Comment: ' <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />'

Comment: Same issue after changing color format

Comment: Check your `layout/app_bar_main`, `menu/activity_main_drawer`, and `layout/nav_header_main`. Probably because you use vector drawable there.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך i did i removed all vectors bt still not resolve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your drawable. See if there are any file in drawable-v24. Copy all the contents in drawable-v24 to drawable. I had a similar issue recently and doing so solved my issue.

Comment: I have files on both. should I delete from drawable-24 ?

Answer (score 1):

This problem mostly occurs when the version of your appcompat library and design support library doesn't match.

It should be something like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' // appcompat library
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1' //design support library
```

Comment: Please check the gradle file

Comment: please share one

Comment: **I did Please Check Again**

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes may be you are using app:itemTextColor="@drawable/textcolor"
in this you have to set color file not drawable file.

Comment: '<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:itemIconTint="#f760e8"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
'

Comment: Issue still exist

Comment: Try to clean the project and rebuild

Answer (score 1):

Check your drawable file (res/drawable). See if there are any file in drawable-v24 (examble:- res/drawable/bacground.xml-v24).

Copy all the contents in drawable-v24 to drawable. I had a similar issue recently and doing so solved my issue.